# How would I call delete on a pointer to a Mat destructor ~Mat()

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this function to delete a pointer to A Mat that I was advised to update to call the Mat destructor to facilitate the delete:

```
    void cv_x_Mat(void* ptr) {
        delete (Mat*)ptr;
    }
```

This doesn't seem to be compiling though, didn't post error, because I thought anyone would be able to see the error thats familiar with Destructors. Any help is appreciated.

```
    void cv_x_Mat(void* ptr) {
        Mat::~Mat() {delete ptr;};
    }
```

Comment: the second one is a *definition*, no code gets called. what#s wrong with the 1st idea exactly ?

Comment: @berak I was told I should call the Mat destructor to do the delete, my code was viewed by a colleague and he said it would be better that way...Thanks for replying to my post

Comment: @berak , can you show me how to call delete on the destructor, I was told that is neccesary for my project

Comment: did you mean this? : void cv_x_Mat1(void* ptr) {((Mat*)ptr)->~Mat();}  (e.g calling the destructor explicitly instead via the delete call ?)

Comment: again, your 1st attempt is total valid

Comment: @berak I was told verbatim to call delete on the destructor..Is that the best method.  the guy that told me that is a Software Analyst that use to work for DOD. But I notice you write answers all the time, when I search S.O. so I was kinda wondering whose right, ie calling delete on a destructor, my way or something like Marol's idea.

Comment: Marol's idea boils down to your 1st attempt, too. and honestly, i got no idea what your collegue means. pester him again on monday please, we're all curious now. let's see his solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment because I lack rep, but I'm the colleague referenced by user3517736. We're working on OpenCV bindings to other languages and so we're tackling the tough problem of memory management across language boundaries.

What I was suggesting he do was exactly what marol suggested. I was under the assumption (now confirmed) that that release would be called by the destructor, so what he needs to do is pass an extern "C" function that calls delete on the Mat pointer like so:

```
extern "C" void cv_delete_Mat(Mat* self) {
    delete self;
}
```

And pass that as the object's finalizer to the garbage collector in the target language with proper C interop (Common Lisp in user3517736's case).

In Haskell (my target), this would mean treating the pointer as a ForeignPtr and explicitly constructing it with a finalizer that calls cv_Mat_delete. I can expand on this if anyone is curious.

The confusion I think arose because I was trying to explain that a language with C interop and a GC will probably try to call free on the pointer, which is not correct on objects initialized via new. The issue is further compounded in that the finalizer may be called antecedent to a call to free -- this is obviously problematic, and the correct answer in this case is to either explicitly call the destructor, or perhaps just Mat::release(). The former obviously generalizes to other OpenCV types as well.

So here's the most general solution that should work with most FFIs, and generalizes to other types pretty easily:

```
extern "C" void cv_delete_Mat(Mat* self) {
    self->~Mat();
}
```

Of course, that (implicit) call to free is still wrong, but there's not much that can be done about it without trying to expand the FFI itself to include C++ -- in which case all of this is moot anyway.

Hopefully that answers both the OP's question as well as the follow ups on this page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mat::release() to free matrix memory:

```
cv::Mat *ptr = new cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC3);
ptr->setTo(cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
// some code
ptr->release(); // DON'T release manually ptr->data
delete ptr;     // this will call delete[] on ptr->data
```

You can even omit release() because cv::Mat destructor will do it for you:

```
cv::Mat *ptr = new cv::Mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC3);
ptr->setTo(cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
// some code
delete ptr;     // this will call delete[] on ptr->data
```

And Mat::release is delete-safe. If does twice, will not cause any bad side effect.